# Generating ListView Adapter programmatically during runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

Is it possible to define an adapter for a ListView during runtime with Layouts like it is possible for Activities?

I searching for a solution because I can't use any XML-file, so even the adapter layout should be written in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. You have to define a new ArrayAdapter inside the setListAdapter()-methode and override the getView()-methode.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, R.layout.list_item, strings) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;

    if (null == convertView) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(getItem(position));

    return row;
}
});
```

Comment: Source: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications